# How to remove a revision from a bazaar repository?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

Is it possible to completely remove a revision from a bazaar repository? I'm asking this because someone just committed a full database dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use uncommit or rebase (from bzr-rebase/bzr-rewrite plugin) command.